# Powershell - Monthly Scheduled Task Trigger

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm currently automating the creation of scheduled tasks via Powershell, and I'm using the `New-ScheduledTaskAction`, `New-ScheduledTaskTrigger`, and `Register-ScheduledTask` commands. Now, I have a few jobs that need to run under the following conditions :

- Run once every Friday
- Run once on the 1st of every month
- Run once on the 10th day of every month

While the [technet documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649821(v=wps.630).aspx) for the `New-ScheduledTaskTrigger` command specifies a `Daily` and `Weekly` time span parameter, I do not see one for `Monthly`, which is critical for defining the run times above.

In the few years I've been using Powershell, I can't think of an instance where I *could* do something via the standard UI interface, that I *couldn't* accomplish using one of the available commands.

Is this just flat out not available here, or am I missing something?

**UPDATE #1**

I just stumbled upon this [SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/995889/powershell-for-creating-a-scheduled-task-in-which-runs-monthly), which does look promising, but references PSV3 instead of PSV4 - going to give it a shot and report back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I said in the original post, the SuperUser question above looked promising, but ultimately did not work with PSV4, and the example given in the post was basically a copy\paste job with almost no context.

I realized I could leverage [Schtasks.exe](http://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html) from my Powershell script to handle the monthly aggregations, and it's fairly easy to set up, albeit somewhat tedious :

```
# set the trigger depending on time, span, and day
$runSpan = $task.SpanToRun;

if ($runSpan.Equals("Daily"))
{            
    $trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At $task.TimeToRun
    Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName $task.TaskName -User $Username -Password $Password -Description $task.Description       
}

if ($runSpan.Equals("Weekly"))
{            
    $trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Weekly -At $task.TimeToRun -DaysOfWeek $task.DayToRun
    Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName $task.TaskName -User $Username -Password $Password -Description $task.Description
}        

#  script out SchTasks magic to create the monthly tasks
if ($runSpan.Equals("Monthly"))
{
    $taskParams = @("/Create",
                "/TN", $task.TaskName, 
                "/SC", "monthly", 
                "/D", $task.DayToRun, 
                "/ST", $task.TimeToRun, 
                "/TR", $filePath, 
                "/F", #force
                "/RU", $Username,
                "/RP", $Password);

    # supply the command arguments and execute  
    #schtasks.exe $taskParams
     schtasks.exe @taskParams
}
```

I'm using an in-script class to keep track of all the task properties (`$task.TimeToRun`, `$task.DayToRun`, etc.), iterating over a list of those, applying the Powershell implementation for daily and weekly tasks, then switching to SchTasks.exe for the monthly spans.

One thing I want to note, is that at first glance, I thought setting the user context under which the *task* runs could be achieved with the `U` and `P` arguments, but that is not the case. That specifies the creds that *Schtasks.exe runs under* - in order to set the user context for the task, you must use `RU` and `RP`.

In addition to the link above, these two were also very helpful :

http://coding.pstodulka.com/2015/08/02/programmatically-scheduling-powershell-scripts-in-task-scheduler/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Here I am finding this 2.5 years later & it looks to me like New-ScheduledTaskTrigger *still* doesn't allow you to define monthly schedules. Can that be right?

Comment: @RoyPardee That is correct. We've actually scrapped a lot of our old windows based tasks for k8s linux workers and cronjobs, which use a flexible expression based scheduling mechanism (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/).

Comment: And also support with runAs gMSA account, add: `/RU 'domain/gMSA$'`